# How to pass ajax val to php variable on the same page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii2

```
$('#test-test_id').change(function() {
        var myValue = $(this).val();
    });

// $getMyValue = $(this).val();
```

For example, by using the code above, I want to pass `$(this).val` to the php variable on the same page. How is this possible?

Comment: make an xmlhttprequest or use a form and submit

Comment: Agree with @Ghost. Calling itself with parameters makes AJAX useless here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`windown.location` can reload page with parameters . You can try that in sending val to php variable like below...

```
<input type="text" id="test-test_id">
<?php
   if(isset($_GET["val"])){
     $sent = $_GET["val"];
     echo "<h2>".$sent."</h2>";
   }
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#test-test_id').change(function() {
        var myValue = $(this).val();                            
        window.location = '?val=' + myValue; //redirect page with para ,here do redirect current page so not added file name .                      
    });
```

Update code for without refresh

```
$('#test-test_id').change(function() {

        var myValue = $(this).val();
        $.get("",{val:myValue},function(data){
            $("body").html(data);
        });               
     //you can try with many option eg. "$.post","$.get","$.ajax"
     //But this function are not reload page so need to replace update data to current html
    });   
</script>
```

Comment: hi david. is it possible for me to do it without refreshing the page? because my selection in the (#test-test_id) will change back to default value

Comment: wow. that works perfectly. thanks. but my selection is still going back to default. For example, my drop down contains data male and female. Once  i choose female. the drop down list will return back to male. how can i prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is a bit complicated, first you must make an AJAX request  where you pass the variable from client to server, like this:

```
$.post('/', { variable: "your_value_here" }, function() {
   alert('Variable passed');
});
```

This simple code, made in Javascript sends a POST Request to a URL that you pass to function as the first parameter, in this case we pass to $.post the same page. Now, in PHP you must handle the POST request:

```
session_start(); // We start a session where we'll set the value of variable.
if(isset($_POST['variable'])) {
   $_SESSION['your_var'] = $_POST['variable'];
} else {
   /* Your page code */ 
}
```

You can also register the variable in the database, but if it's a temporary variable you can just register it in the session. Remember to use `session_start()` in every page before using `$_SESSION` global variable.

Helpful documentation:
[jQuery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) , 
[PHP Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

Comment: I think asker wants to call the page itself.

Comment: What do you mean with this? If you want to make the whole script in a single page, know that you're able to do that. I'm editing my answer to show you how to do this.